# GitLab CI runner doesn't build

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have just installed gitlab-ci-multi-runner by following the documentation https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/install/linux-repository.md

I use the public server ci.gitlab.com and the registration of the runner seems OK (the runner appears with a green light).
With debug activated I can see that the runner fetch regularly the CI server.

But when a new commit is pushed no build is done.
Everything is green: https://ci.gitlab.com/projects/4656 but no test is done...

My .gitlab-ci.yml is pretty simple:

```
before_script:
  - apt install python3-pip
  - pip3 install -q -r requirements.txt
master:
  script: "make test"
  only:
    - master
script:
  - python setup.py test
```

By the way I can find any error message and I don't know where to search.

I am pretty knew to CI and there is perhaps an obvious point I am missing.

Comment: rspec:
python setup.py test

Comment: For those following along at home (_hi!_), the line `- apt install python3-pip` should read `- apt-get install -y python3-pip` instead. That said, shouldn't the `python:3` Docker image already provision this dependency for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try. this is assuming your pyunit tests are in a file called runtests.py in the working directory.

```
before_script:
  - apt install python3-pip
  - pip3 install -q -r requirements.txt

master:
  script: "python runtests.py"
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: The script section was actually non relevant. Thanks!

Comment: Glad i can help. I just got started with it last week myself. Understand what you are going though :) Its pretty easy system once you get the hang of it.